Importing Mobility translations from one rails record to another
A rails application has two classes.
The first is a set of base data, whereas a second
is a class of customised user data - some added ad hoc, but others drawn from the first class.  The class structures are different.
Thus an action will provide parameters that allow to query the base data records and create a new record
categori = Categori.find(params[:categori_id])  
@user_categori = UserCategori.create(sequence: categori.sequence, name: categori.name [etc])

But assuming both tables have a translatable name_locale variable, how can the base data be imported to the second class?
The following is attempted using the getter/setter methods suggested by the gem
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
  translation = categori.name_locale(locale: locale.to_sym)      
  @user_categori.categori_locale_backend.write(locale.to_sym, translation)
end

But the logs do not show any writing. The locale and transalation are readily available, but the write function does not appear to fire.

You should add a mention that you're using mobility to the title or body of the question. It's easy to miss the tags.

The following  will extract the main table's translation values
and turn them into parameters for the object to be updated.
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
  translation = categori.name_locale(locale: locale.to_sym)
  params["categori_locale_#{locale}".to_sym] = translation
end
@user_categori.update(user_categori_params)

